# Cannot get correct html from VB

Tags: python, vb.net

In VB, I wrote:

```
Dim client As New System.Net.WebClient()
Dim sourceString As String = client.DownloadString("https://www.facebook.com/audi/posts/10155153026226470")
```

However, the two string does not contain the content of the webpage. How to write the correct VB code?

Comment: Where is the difference? Your VB.Net version should run.

Comment: The content is different.

Comment: Any other ways to get the html cod in VB?

Comment: You can try it using WebRequest. But you did not tell us where the difference is in the received string.

Comment: I show the real url and now you can check what I mean.